# Where did the line "Don't tell Harry" originate from?

Tags: spider-man, quotes, marvel, spider-man-2002

I remember when the original Spider-Man movie hit theaters (the one with Toby Maguire), the line "Don't tell Harry" was spoken a lot.  When it was first spoken, I remember people giving that familiarity/giddy laugh, like it was something they had been waiting on hearing. However, I honestly don't remember it being used in the comics or the 90's show.

So, was this line pulled from the comics or tv show? Or was it something done just for the movie in an attempt to create nostalgia?

Comment: The line originally does come from the comics. Upon his original defeat/"death" his last words were to the tune of "Don't Tell Harry". That took place sometime in the 60's, it's somewhat unlikely that's what the audience was laughing at though. The line is foreshadowed because "not telling Harry" is a theme throughout the movie.

Answer (score 8):

The line was spoken in the first Spider-man movie with Tobey Maguire. It was when Peter happened to run across Mary Jane on the streets of New York City after she ran out of her job as a waitress being yelled at by her boss.

She told Peter "don't tell Harry" because she was ashamed of not immediately succeeding as an actress. She even states that she's afraid of Harry finding out because her being a waitress would make her unworthy of being his girlfriend, in as many words.

The giddy laugh came in that scene after Peter says "Why don't I come by and grab lunch some evening?" They both laughed at his flub, but agree that it would be nice to see each other again.

As they're leaving, she turns to Peter and reminds him, "Don't tell Harry!" and continues to laugh at Peter for being the dork she always loved.

There was no nostalgia implied in the scene. It was never intended as a reference to anything in the comics. Mary Jane and Harry never had any sort of relationship other than friends. The reaction between the two characters were to Peter's awkwardness.

This mildly humorous scene was the likely source of the audience's amusement/laughter.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question, "No. It was from the scene." By explaining what happened in the scene, and why they were laughing giddily, I was pointing out that there was no nostalgia implied. It was all in-scene.

Comment: @Robert: It absolutely answers your question. There is absolutelyno nostalgia involved, nothing implied at all in the line whatsoever, except that they laugh about a mistake after Mary-Jane first uses it. It then takes a darker turn when Norman Osbourne uses it later in the film. It was establishing a new line, not using an old one. Don't get upset just because the correct answer wasn't the one you wanted.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I'm not sure where you're getting the idea that I got upset with the answer given.  I simply stated that it didn't answer the question I was asking.  I asked if the line had any origins anywhere else due to the way the **audience laughed with nostalgia**.  Not the actors.  Seriously, people need to read the question and stop making it out as though I became offensive or hostile because the answer didn't answer the question I asked until later in the comments.

Comment: @Robert Do not to take offense when an answer attempts to correct a perceived misconception. Your assumption was that the laughter you heard was due to a large group of very comic-savvy individuals enjoying a moment of nostalgia, this answer suggests that the audience is laughing at an (at least mildly) humorous scene. As such, it is still an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @GorchestopherH. I never got that the OP was referring to the **audience** laughing in the question.

Comment: **When it was first spoken, I remember people giving that familiarity/giddy laugh, like it was something they had been waiting on hearing.**

Answer (score -3):

Lol, no. This line is from Norman Osborne a.k.a the Green Goblin, when he finally accepts defeat after he accidentally impaled himself with his glider.